# Filter files with glob command

Tags: python

I have files with datetimes like :
file_20180316200006.txt
file_20180316200505.txt

and i want to group files every 6 min (exemple : groupe files from 00 to 05 min, and from 06 to 12 min...etc)

I am using glob command like :

```
for minute in range(0,59,6):
    glob.glob("%s[%02i-%02i]*" % file_names,minute,minute+5)
```

but this retrieve all files

Any help about this 
Thank you all

Comment: first, `glob.glob("%s[%02i-%02i]*" % file_names,minute,minute+5) ` should be `glob.glob("%s[%02i-%02i]*" % (file_names,minute,minute+5)) ` else minute args are passed to `glob` not to formatting operator.

Comment: then, patterns aren't as powerful. This cannot be your real code. just glob without the minute thing, and use another grouping method.

Comment: To be clear, fnmatch ranges specify ranges of *characters*, not ranges of *numbers*. If you write `[14-65]`, that matches only one character, which may be any of the following: `1` - the digit 1; `4-6` - the digits 4 through 6, and `5`, the digit 5 (specified a second, duplicative time).